# Non-blocking input in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, slime

I have program that runs for long periods of time and I'd like to interrupt it but not with ctrl-c ctrl-c. I also don't want the system to wait for a keystroke every so often. Instead, if I do press a key, I want it to wrap things up and exit. I found `listen` and `read-char-no-hang` but I can't get it to work right. Here's what I tried to do

```
(let ((f nil))
  (loop while (not f) do
     (if (listen)
       (setf f t)))))
```

Obviously, this is doing less than a sloth on Xanax as far as finding key=-presses. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of lisp running where?

Comment: Likely to get what you want may well be implementation dependent, so which Lisp are you using?

Comment: @bmargulies @Will Hartung - CCL running on Aquamacs with slime

Comment: Could you explain a little more? Are you watching for a keypress in a different thread from your long running process? Is the work broken in to little bits and part of the same loop where you are polling for a keypress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCL has multithreading, I believe. You could try spawning a worker thread in the background and have a control thread doing a blocking read, and then communicating via a special variable.  The following works in Lispworks, I don't have CCL available.  You'd have to translate the mp:process-run-function to whatever CCL uses to spawn threads:

```lisp
(defparameter *f* nil)
(defun cmd-loop ()
  (setf *f* nil)
  (mp:process-run-function "work" () #'do-work)  ; Spawn worker
  (read-char *terminal-io*)                      ; Blocking read
  (setf *f* t))
(defun do-work ()
  (loop while (not *f*)
        do 
          (format t "~a " *f*)
          (finish-output)))
(cmd-loop)
```

The big assumption I'm making here is that CCL multithreading works similarily to LW multithreading, so that both threads can access the shared state variable `*f*`.

Comment: In the example above the `cmd-loop` isn't really a loop at all, of course.  I kept the name, because in my experience, in the real world it probably would be, and would do something more interesting than just quitting.

Answer (score 0):

I use SLIME for these things.
I usually start lisp on a remote computer like this:

```
whoplisp@laptop:~$ ssh -L4005:127.0.0.1:4005 remotecomputer
whoplisp@remotecomputer:~$ sbcl
(require :asdf)
(require :swank)
(setf swank:*dedicated-output-stream-port* nil)
(swank:create-server)
```

Then I can start a slime session on the laptop from within emacs:

```
M-x slime-connect
localhost
4005
C-x C-f /ssh:remotehost:project/test.lisp
```

You'll have to setup TRAMP for this to work.
You should also make sure that you have a sensible ssh setup (if you want to work remotely).
Add this to /etc/ssh/ssh_config. It will speed up handshakes for many ssh connections.

```
Host remotehost
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath /tmp/%r@%h:%p
```

However if you just want to have things running on your local machine everything is much easier. You can reconnect with SLIME and use M-x slime-list-threads to stop jobs you started earlier in the lisp image.